# PHP Date and Time formatting

Tags: php, date, time

Let's say for instance I have a date that is sent to me like this: **2011-12-14 16:28:14**

How can I remove the time at the end and only keep the date using php?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, which most articles I have found are pertaining to converting the entire date and time into another format. I simply want to exclude the time and only use the date.

Comment: **Without converting: [demo](https://eval.in/235233)**